# Dynamic filling of Month and Year from TODAY()

Tags: excel

Is there a way to obtain Month-Year from today's date and fill it down for the past 5 years?

[image]

such that it will dynamically change according to the month and year from my date.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `EDATE()` to subtract one month in each row.  Enter the following formula into `A4`:

```
=EDATE(A1, -1)
```

Then copy this formula down the `A` column.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, the function helped as I worked around it. Have a nice day!

Comment: Tim: since you did not lock the cell reference $A$1, how did you get that to work by just copying down?  did you mean to reference A3 instead?